# AIR <-> Android communication

Tags: android, air, bluetooth, communication, wifi

I'm looking for a way have some way of communication between an AIR application that runs on a desktop and an Android application (that obviously runs on a phone). Basically, I plan to make the desktop application controllable via an application on an Android phone.

Grant Skinner did a similar thing with his [Androideroids](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/06/androideroids.html) game, which is playable via multiple Android devices on a central computer. Sadly he didn't tell anything about how he managed to do this.

What I would like to achieve is a communication via bluetooth and/or wifi; when the application is running, the phone will be in the same network as the desktop computer. Preferably I'm looking for a solution that allows running a native Android application on the phone, but if it works much easier with an AIR on Android app, I'm fine going that way too.

If required I am also willing to set up some service on the desktop computer that the Android app is communicating with which then relays the commands to the AIR application. But given that Flash supports p2p connections, I guess there is an easier way.

With this question I'm not looking for any code or examples. Instead I would like you to give me some hints on how this could work, what techniques are appropriate for this and how it would roughly work on the particular platform, so I can research on that more detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if Grant Skinner used this for Androideroids, but you should check out [Adobe Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) to accomplish communication between two flash players.

from Ryan Stewart's [blog entry on Stratus](http://blog.digitalbackcountry.com/2009/06/building-a-p2p-chat-application-with-adobe-stratus/):

> Adobe Stratus is a hosted beta service
>   that uses new RTMFP functionality in
>   Flash Player 10 to connect directly
>   instead of having to round trip
>   between the server and the instance of
>   the player.